# how to get the latest Received message in one account?

Tags: microtransaction

I want to query the latest Received message in one account,I try "let tx = await account.listMessages(1, 1, 1)",After I test,it returned the oldest received message,not the recent

Answer (score 1):

You should list all received messages with `account.listMessages(0, 0, 1)` and then look at the timestamp to find the latest message

Comment: There are too many received messages in my account,so for example I just need to get the latest  500 received messages everytime,